# Kotlin extension TextView

Tags: android, kotlin, textview, kotlin-android-extensions

I have this TextView in my layout

```
<TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            tools:text="text"/>
```

Now I want to set the text of the this Textview with Kotlin Android Extension. So I added `apply plugin: 'kotlin-android-extensions'` in my `build.gradle` file. 
Now in my class I want to set text in the TextView with

```
textView.text("MyText")
```

If I import the textView with autocomplete "alt + return" the import is not the synthetic import rather the import to the resource direct `com.package.R.id.textView` 
At the end I have an Integer Object instead of a TextView

Can someone explain me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: try - textView.text = "My Test"

Comment: I have no method `text` because the textView is not a TextView rather an Integer object

Comment: Can you post the code in the kt file?

Comment: What is this Class? Java or Kotlin?

Comment: just add this in import statement **import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*** and then use **textView.setText("your_text");**

Comment: use either `text = R.string.something` or `setText("something")` you cannot use `text = "something"`

Comment: textView.setText("Your text") its working perfectly here in kotlin file. @DudiDudewitz

Comment: Try removing the unnecessary imports and try importing kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.* again

Comment: So the problem is that instead of importing kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.your_activity.* you imported com.package.R.id.textView

Comment: @mTak it is a abstract kotlin class

Comment: @mTak @Aarth Tandel yes. I've tried to import the synthetic import 
manually lik this `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.myLayout.*
` but this does not work

Comment: @DudiDudewitz I'm not sure I understand: you want to use a TextView from a layout in your project in an abstract Kotlin class?

Comment: @mTak yes, correctly

Comment: oh now i see the my problem there. I use a method, that expect a view as argument. Inside the method I mapped the textView which is came from the parameter argument. In this can't use kotlin android extensions

Answer (score 0):

**Use textView.setText("  ") instead of textView.text("  ") with your textview like-**

textView.setText("Your text here");

Comment: still an Integer Object

Comment: Can you show me what are you exactly facing.? B'coz i run this with kotlin file and its working fine.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the you have imported the wrong package just remove the package`com.package.R.id.textView` 
And instead of this
You need to `import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.your_layout_file_name.*`

Comment: can you show your logcat errors. And one thing are you using it in activity or fragment?

Answer (score 0):

First import this 
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.layoutfile.*;

and then call textview and assign settext (don't use alt+enter)